# Which one is the correct usage, No plus neither nor, no plus either or?

Tags: neither-nor

Given:
1. No consonant cluster is possible word initially.
2. No consonant cluster is possible word finally.

A. No consonant cluster is possible neither word initially nor word finally.
B. No consonant cluster is possible either word initially or word finally.

Comment: This type of question would be better asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use *either-or*.

*No* plus *neither-nor* creates a double negative ie a positive, which is not used in English unless you intentionally want a double negative.

That's my answer purely on grammatical grounds, but I find your examples difficult to understand - is this for a program you are writing? If just for normal prose it would be better phrased as:

> A consonant cluster is not possible either at the beginning of a
>   word or the end.
>   (That, at any rate, is what I take your examples to mean.)

Comment: I don't have any problem with your paraphrase. That is an easy way to express. But I needed the format "Negative" plus ... I wanna make sure which way is right!

Answer (score 0):

No consonant cluster is possible either word initially or word finally.
OR
Consonant clusters are possible neither word initially nor word finally.